# Is it a problem to travel with a passport that has an extended expiry date?

Tags: visas, passports, australia

I will be traveling to Melbourne, Australia with my old passport which has an expiration date that has been extended for 2 years. Do I need to do anything? I asked some of my friends who went to Australia and they said no issue. I've looked at the website and it seems that I need to submit Form 929. My flight is 2 weeks time.

Comment: Please search very carefully. To my experience, an absolute majority of countries do not accept extended passports anymore.

Comment: Somewhat related - https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/news/visa-pages-no-longer-issued.html

Comment: Have you already applied for an Australian visa using your old passport details?

Comment: I had no trouble at all using an extended USA passport, that had originally been issued for one year as a replacement to a "mutilated" one (cover was coming off).

Comment: @GregHewgill yeah, my visa is link to my old password that was extended..

Answer (score 1):

It would be advisable to file [Form 929](https://www.border.gov.au/Forms/Documents/929.pdf) as, in comment, you advised that you had an earlier visa application associated to your passport, albeit with a now-different expiry date.

As Australian Immigration and Border authorities note:

> You need to advise the department of any changes to your passport details before and after a visa is granted to you. Where a new passport has been issued or you hold an additional passport(s), you need to provide a certified copy
>   of the bio-data page of this new or additional passport(s) with this form in order for the department to confirm your identity.